# What is the size or scale of the world of Greyhawk?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, maps, greyhawk

I'm looking to run a campaign in Greyhawk, but I'm not sure of the actual size of the place.  I have found [several](http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/) [maps](http://mapsofgreyhawk.blogspot.com/) [online](https://web.archive.org/web/20131206225330/http://www.sodabob.com/roleplay/dnd/Maps/), but not one map has a scale of any kind that I can see.  I know I've seen one with it before.  I believe it's [this map](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_kuTawUlRPfY/TH3rirAhTGI/AAAAAAAAAno/yh6u5QYBFjQ/s400/Greyhawk+full+greymap.jpg) in the lower right corner, but that one is much too small to see.

I'm aware that for my own campaign I can make 1 hex be any size I want it to be.  It could be 20 miles, 30 miles, or 50 or 100 or more and it doesn't really matter.  My question is what the official answer is, because I may wish to use a published module at some point.  Even knowing something basic like the distance in miles between Dyvers and Greyhawk, or Dyvers and Verbobonc would be useful information.  Heck, even knowing something general like the *travel time* between Greyhawk and Dyvers would be useful, because you can infer a lot from that.  I know I've read places where they speak of the distances between locations before.  I want to say Verbobonc and the infamous Village of Homlett, but I am not sure where I read that anymore.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Here's the big version of one of the maps you linked to](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-YGEy9dEKRNk/WdQhx6VzVUI/AAAAAAAAA3o/cuHisfZdNqsKFF0bDewoJczYlyjq0IuNwCLcBGAs/s1600/Greyhawk%2Bfull%2Bgreymap.jpg). Zoom in to 100% resolution and you'll see the scale in the bottom right of the image: 1 hex = 65 miles.

This map was included with the D&D 3rd Edition Living Greyhawk Gazetteer, so it's about as official as any source you're going to find. Note that the political boundaries represent the world as it looks like *after* the classic modules.

[This high-detail fan-made map by Anna B. Meyer](https://www.annabmeyer.com/2020/01/21/flanaess-576-2020/) also comes with a scale at the top of the legend on the right side. (It's available in multiple versions: with no grid, with a 12-mile hex grid, and with a 30-mile hex grid.)

Answer (score 16):

Sure.  [This original Greyhawk map](http://mapsofgreyhawk.blogspot.com/2010/08/west-flanness.html), also known as the "Darlene" map; has a scale of 1 hex = 30 miles per the World of Greyhawk Glossography from the 1e boxed set:

> Each map hexagon is 10 leagues across (30 miles).  Travel rates are given in miles per day.

It's about 4 hexes from Dyvers to Greyhawk, so that's about 120 miles.  For more maps and info you probably want to go to [Canonfire!](http://www.canonfire.com/), the largest last bastion of Greyhawk lovers. Or for maps, probably [annabmeyer.com](https://www.annabmeyer.com/greyhawk-maps/) for some more updated maps of all of GH.

Comment: Anna Meyer produces some gorgeous work. I'm glad you included a link to her stuff!